# what is the best way to deal with a image for compression by Arithmetic coding?

Tags: python, node.js, image-compression

I have been working on a project in `node js` for compression of `.txt` file. So far i have been succeeded in that goal by using `Arithmetic coding` for `encoding` and `decoding` of data but now i want use that code for compression of images but i can't get the idea how to do that. My main problem is how should i read data from image to compress. I did not have slightest idea how to do that with `Buffer` , `stream` or even with `Blob` (by sometime searching on interest theses were the possible way to do that.).

I knew that dealing with images in `Python` is quite easy so i though to make script to read images with `python`. For just now i am not integrating `Python` and `Node js` that will be later step.

I had small experience with some `python` libraries like `open-csv` and `Pillow (PIL)`. So far i have used `cv2.imread()` function to read an image and store it as `binary` in `.txt` file. as for now i have not integrated it with `Node js`.

```
from cv2 import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('cat.png',0)

with open("cat.txt", 'wb') as out:
    out.write(img1.tobytes())
```

Now i use that `cat.txt` file and read that data by `fs` in `node js` and than compress and decompress it
by `Arithmetic coding`.

**Now to main problem :**

> When i read image in `python` and store it in `cat.txt` it's size is quite bigger than `cat.png` file. Even such that after compressing that `cat.txt` file the resultant `compressed_cat.txt` is bigger than that of `cat.png`.

> `cat.png` = 242kb,   `cat.txt(before compression)` = 971kb,   `compressed_cat.txt(after compression)` = 251kb

I think i am reading or storing the file incorrectly. I don't know how to overcome that problem.

*Some additional help needed*

- Is there any way to process image in `node js` like in `python` so i don't need to integrate it later. I have tried `Multer` and `Jimp` but i could not find anything in it like `python open-csv`
- And i don't know how to store the data after compression because mostly it is stored in either `.zip` or `.rar`. I have never stored/read data in/form that type of format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong direction for the solution. But [@Harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267477/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-a-image-for-compression-by-arithmetic-coding/63272306#63272306) comment helped `I think you just want to read the bytes from image file directly, so you can convert it back to the original image file`.
I made 2 big changes

**First the way to read the image.**

I don't need `python` to read/write the image as it easily can be done in `node-js`.

```
const fs = require("fs");

let data = fs.readFileSync('Cat.png', 'binary');

fs.writeFileSync('Cat_Copy.png', data, 'binary');
```

**Second Selecting the Right file to Compress**

> Mostly `.jpeg`, `.jpg`and `.png` are already compressed so normal compression techniques does not work on them. But `.tiff` files are not compressed and at least my algorithm works on this format. Still it is not very efficient.

**Third Selecting the Right format to save the compress file**

> Well that was not a big problem as we can save it `without any extension` what does really matters is the encoding in which it is saved. Well in `js` `ucs2` takes less space on disk than `utf8`. I am saving it as `filename.ac` as it represents `Arithmetic Coding`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but I think the following information would help -

The image formats like .png, .jpg, etc already represent image in a compressed format. Some are not lossy, but most commonly used for storage are lossy to minimize size. So, honestly, I doubt any text compression algorithms could beat already existing image compression formats.

One thing which I think is wrong with your approach is reading the image using open-cv. It gives you a multi-dimentional array representation of the image if I am not mistaken. Great if you want to work with image, but I think you just want to read the bytes from image file directly, so you can convert it back to the original image file. Now, how you work with bytes, or underlying bits is upto you. I hope this answers part of your question.